# setting attribute values using telerik controls

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, telerik

How can I assign values to attributes using telerik controls?

For e.g. I can assign the Name attribute for the below Dropdown "Priority", but dont find a way to assigning an ID or class attributes.

```
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("Priority").Items(items => {
items.Add().Text("Select").Value("Select");
items.Add().Text("Select").Value("High");
items.Add().Text("Select").Value("Medium");
items.Add().Text("Select").Value("Low")
})%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `HtmlAttributes()` method.

Like this:

```
<% Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
                  .Name("Priority")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new{@class="className",@id="idName"})
%>
```